# Android studio: ScrollView не уменьшается после увеличения и последующим уменьшением контента

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-scrollview

День добрый, столкнулся с такой проблемой, буду благодарен помощи.
Суть такова, вот моя xml разметка страницы:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/mainBackground">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:overScrollMode="never">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/some_id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

                <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/some_id_fragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/some_id"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45sp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:alpha="0.0"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20sp"
            app:cardElevation="2sp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при увеличении контента фрагмента и в последующем его уменьшении прокручиваемый контент не уменьшается, что в итоге приводит к такой ситуации:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас `ScrollView` имеет высоту `match_parent`.
Без `fillViewport="true"` он может не растянуться на всего родителя, если контента слишком мало, но если он не сузится после уменьшения количества контента - это не то чтобы неправильное поведение.
Если вы хотите, чтобы `ScrollView` был во весь экран, то добавьте `fillViewport="true"`, в этому случае после уменьшения контента возможность скролла должна пропадать.
Если вы хотите, чтобы скролл сужался вместе с контентом - поставьте его высоту `wrap_content`

Comment: Спасибо большое:)